# Can I avoid using batches in Keras Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Due to the nature of my task, I have to use a batch size of 1. Rather than having all the layers with outputs like `(1, 28)` can I just not use batches to get outputs like `(28)`, this would reduce a lot of the clutter in my code.

The `tf.keras.Input`'s seem to put everything into batches but I need them to form a `tf.keras.Model`.

Comment: Did you actually try to use a batch size of 1 and got an error, or what?

Comment: @desertnaut it works with a batch size of 1. All of the layers I make have to essentially throw away this dimension and then add it back in at the end. It would be more convenient to not have the batch dimension at all.

Comment: You cannot do that, neither I understand exactly *why* you would want or need to.

Comment: @desernaut Everything has an extra useless dimension which is inconvenient and makes the code less readable.

Comment: I am afraid you'll have to live with that.